# How to return a list to caller method using async method in C#

Tags: c#

Can anyone help, how can I return the list to caller method in asynchronous function.

Here is my code, I want to return list named as `ResultList`

```
public class ResultData
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int BatchId { get; set; }
}

private static List<Data> ResultList = new List<Data>();

public void TSReCalculation(int piGroupId, int piIssuerId, DateTime pdFromDate, DateTime ldToDate, int piFormulaId, int piIsProcessedType, int piIsSeriesReStart, int piIsPLCalculate, int piIsIncludeEditedScoreint)
{
     Common.callSpForTS(piGroupId, piIssuerId, pdFromDate, ldToDate, piFormulaId, piIsProcessedType, piIsSeriesReStart, piIsPLCalculate, piIsIncludeEditedScoreint);
}

public static async void callSpForTS(int piGroupId, int piIssuerId, DateTime pdFromDate, DateTime ldToDate, int piFormulaId, int piIsProcessedType, int piIsSeriesReStart, int piIsPLCalculate, int piIsIncludeEditedScoreint)
{
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                    try
                    {
                        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        dbModel.ResultData item = new dbModel.ResultData();
                        item.Description= "succesfulll"
                        item.Status = 1;
                        item.BatchId = 100;
                        ResultList.Add(item);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Common.showMessageBox(ex.Message + "InnerException:" + ex.InnerException, MSG_TYP.Error, "Error Occured");
                    }
            });
        }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

instead of `public static async void callSpForTS` i.e. instead of `void` return type you should keep return type `public static async List<type> callSpForTS`, you dont need common `static list` in your code.

---

**Async All the Way**

Asynchronous code reminds me of the story of a fellow who mentioned that the world was suspended in space and was immediately challenged by an elderly lady claiming that the world rested on the back of a giant turtle. When the man enquired what the turtle was standing on, the lady replied, “You’re very clever, young man, but it’s turtles all the way down!” As you convert synchronous code to asynchronous code, you’ll find that it works best if asynchronous code calls and is called by other asynchronous code—all the way down (or “up,” if you prefer). Others have also noticed the spreading behavior of asynchronous programming and have called it “contagious” or compared it to a zombie virus. Whether turtles or zombies, it’s definitely true that asynchronous code tends to drive surrounding code to also be asynchronous. This behavior is inherent in all types of asynchronous programming, not just the new async/await keywords.

“Async all the way” means that you shouldn’t mix synchronous and asynchronous code without carefully considering the consequences. In particular, it’s usually a bad idea to block on async code by calling Task.Wait or Task.Result. This is an especially common problem for programmers who are “dipping their toes” into asynchronous programming, converting just a small part of their application and wrapping it in a synchronous API so the rest of the application is isolated from the changes. Unfortunately, they run into problems with deadlocks. After answering many async-related questions on the MSDN forums, Stack Overflow and e-mail, I can say this is by far the most-asked question by async newcomers once they learn the basics: “Why does my partially async code deadlock?”

Refer this : [Async/Await - Best Practices in Asynchronous Programming](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx)

apart from that you need to `async/await` in calling function also

```
public async void TSReCalculation(int piGroupId, int piIssuerId, DateTime pdFromDate, DateTime ldToDate, int piFormulaId, int piIsProcessedType, int piIsSeriesReStart, int piIsPLCalculate, int piIsIncludeEditedScoreint)
{
    var returnvalue =await Common.callSpForTS(piGroupId, piIssuerId, pdFromDate, ldToDate, piFormulaId, piIsProcessedType, piIsSeriesReStart, piIsPLCalculate, piIsIncludeEditedScoreint);
}

public static async Task<List<ResultData>> callSpForTS(int piGroupId, int piIssuerId, DateTime pdFromDate, DateTime ldToDate, int piFormulaId, int piIsProcessedType, int piIsSeriesReStart, int piIsPLCalculate, int piIsIncludeEditedScoreint)
{
         return await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                List<ResultData> ResultList = new List<ResultData>();
                    try
                    {
                        sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        dbModel.ResultData item = new dbModel.ResultData();
                        item.Description= "succesfulll"
                        item.Status = 1;
                        item.BatchId = 100;
                        ResultList.Add(item);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        Common.showMessageBox(ex.Message + "InnerException:" + ex.InnerException, MSG_TYP.Error, "Error Occured");
                    }
                 return ResultList;
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: if it is `async` then shouldn't the return type be: `Task<List<ResultData>>` ? Then you can do : `return await Task.Run(() =>` inside the method. Up to now this code should throw this compiler error: `CS1983 The return type of an async method must be void, Task or Task<T>`

Comment: @MongZhu - thanks for pointing it out , SO not givining compiler warning :) but thank you very much for pointing it out

Answer (score -1):

```
        public async void TSReCalculation(int piGroupId, int piIssuerId, DateTime pdFromDate, DateTime ldToDate, int piFormulaId, int piIsProcessedType, int piIsSeriesReStart, int piIsPLCalculate, int piIsIncludeEditedScoreint)
        {
            var result = await Common.callSpForTS(piGroupId, piIssuerId, pdFromDate, ldToDate, piFormulaId, piIsProcessedType, piIsSeriesReStart, piIsPLCalculate, piIsIncludeEditedScoreint);
        }


        public static async Task<List<ResultData>> callSpForTS(int piGroupId, int piIssuerId, DateTime pdFromDate, DateTime ldToDate, int piFormulaId, int piIsProcessedType, int piIsSeriesReStart, int piIsPLCalculate, int piIsIncludeEditedScoreint)
        {
            try
            {
                List<ResultData> myList = new List<ResultData>();
                sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                dbModel.ResultData item = new dbModel.ResultData();
                item.Description = "succesfulll";
                item.Status = 1;
                item.BatchId = 100;
                myList.Add(item);
                return await Task.FromResult(myList);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Common.showMessageBox(ex.Message + "InnerException:" + ex.InnerException, MSG_TYP.Error, "Error Occured");
            }
        }
```

Comment: would you mind to explain what are the differences between your code and that from OP and why this code is supposed to solve the problem?

Comment: What is `ResultList` ? and why do you assume the the type `ResultList` has an `Add` and a `ToListAsync` method?

Comment: @MongZhu ResultList is a 'List'. I add the definition. If you need more clarifications on the various objects read the original code of the question.

Comment: Please paste your code into Visual Studio or LinqPad and try to compile it. "read the original code of the question." Actually I think you should do it. You are trying here to use a variable name `ResultList` as `Type` in: `Task<ResultList>` this will never compile! Furthermore you are doing it again when instantiating the **List** in : `ResultList myList = new ResultList();` if `myList` is supposed to be a list it should be : `List<ResultData>` as it is in your primary declaration. This is also how the return value of the Task has to be declared: `Task<List<ResultData >>`

Comment: Sorry mate but up to now this code is simply wrong and will not even compile.

Comment: @MongZhu you're right, I corrected the code. Sorry.

Comment: sorry mate this will still not compile. You declare that your method returns a `Task<List<ResultData>>` but inside the method you return a `List<ResultData>`. The compiler won't eat it. You need a `Task` in there. Like OP posted in their code: `await Task.Run(() =>{...`.

Comment: @MongZhu I change `return myList;` into `return await Task.FromResult(myList);`